# PhantomJs crashes if you define a bind function

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

PhantomJs doesn't support `bind` method (`Function.prototype.bind`). You can see [Issue #10522](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522) for details.

But you can define it in your js code. A simple version is like this:

```
Function.prototype.bind = Function.prototype.bind || function (thisp) {
    var fn = this;
    return function () {
        return fn.apply(thisp, arguments);
    };
};
```

Or you can use [bind-polyfill](https://github.com/kdimatteo/bind-polyfill).

It works but the problem is that in some cases PhantomJs crashes. Here is my code with a `bind` function that's not part of `Function` prototype but it doesn't change anything, same result for other versions:

```
var webpage = require('webpage');

var bind = function(fn, scope) {
    return function() {
        // console.log(fn);
        return fn.apply(scope, arguments);
    };
};

var WebPage = (function() {

    var WebPage = function() {
        this.page = webpage.create();
        this.page.onConsoleMessage = bind(this.on_console_message, this);
    };

    WebPage.prototype.open = function(url) {
        this.url = url;
        this.page.open(url, bind(this.on_open, this));
    };

    WebPage.prototype.on_open = function(status) {
        if(status != 'success') {
            console.log('page opening status: ' + status);
            phantom.exit();
        }
        this.page.evaluate(function() {
            console.log('here');
        });
        phantom.exit();
    };

    WebPage.prototype.on_console_message = function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    };

    return WebPage;

})();

page = new WebPage();
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/index.html';
page.open(url);
```

And this is index.html file that I serve it with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>


> phantomjs test.js
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Crash-Reporting and file a bug report at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/new with the crash dump file attached: /tmp/1fb7d785-11ed-5883-6c4f0088-5aa5e04f.dmp
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If you uncomment `console.log(fn)` in `bind` function, you can see that it works for `on_open` method but crashes when it tries to access `on_console_message` method.

I have tested it with v1.9.7 and 1.9.8 on two machines (Ubuntu 14.04/x86_64). Seems that `minidump_stackwalk` doesn't contain useful information ([here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11751495/) is one dump)

Comment: It works with PhantomJS 2.0.0.